# MySQL - Count of events across months

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with events that occur & the date they occur in MySQL

The events are in column names EVENT_NAME & the occurrence is in column OCCUR_DATE. The table has hundreds of other columns. I'd like to count the occurrence of each event month by month & display the output as below.

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| Event | Jan-15 | Feb-15 | Mar-15 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| A     |      0 |      1 |      0 |
| B     |      6 |      6 |      3 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I'm currently running SQL query manually for each month & aggregating data using Excel manually. Could I please request some assistance to write up a SQL to output the requested format?

Comment: i would be happy to help you restructure your schema when you get tired of `alter table` every month

Comment: What is format of date and what is data type you are using to store dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it-

```
SELECT event_name, 
COUNT(IF(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%b-%y')='Jan-15',1,NULL)) AS 'Jan-15', 
COUNT(IF(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%b-%y')='Feb-15',1,NULL)) AS 'Feb-15', 
COUNT(IF(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%b-%y')='Sep-15',1,NULL)) AS 'Mar-15' 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY event_name;
```